# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLocalName' of undefined

Tags: android, moodle, typeerror

Have re-created a Moodle mobile app. However, when the app is activated, there is the alert dialog box that will be shown :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLocaleName' of undefined
File: file://android_asset/www/index.html
Line: 67
```

Does anyone knows what is the issue and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the globalization plugin to your project. That should solve this issue.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html